# How to turn this messy block of code into a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have this block of code that works just as I want it to but I want to turn it into a function and reuse it here and there. Below is the working code followed by my conversion into a function. But I'm doing something wrong cause it doesn't work.

Working

```
$('div.destination a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').stop(true,false).animate({
        scrollLeft: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().left 
                        - 1/2 * $(window).width() 
                        + 1/2 * $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).width()
    },
    {
        duration: (Math.abs( $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().left 
                    - $(document).scrollLeft() )) 
                    / 1000 
                    / spaceScaleFactor 
                    / travelRate,
        easing: 'linear',
        queue: false
    });
    $('div.destination').prev().children().children().text(($.attr(this, 'href')).substring(1));
    return false;
});
```

Function and calling it when clicked (not working)

```
// Make the function and replace 'this' with 'x'

function travelToDestination (x) {
        $('html, body').stop(true,false).animate({
            scrollLeft: $( $.attr(x, 'href') ).offset().left 
                            - 1/2 * $(window).width() 
                            + 1/2 * $( $.attr(x, 'href') ).width()
        },
        {
            duration: (Math.abs( $( $.attr(x, 'href') ).offset().left 
                        - $(document).scrollLeft() )) 
                        / 1000 
                        / spaceScaleFactor 
                        / travelRate,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        });
        $('div.destination').prev().children().children().text(($.attr(x, 'href')).substring(1));
        return false;
    });
}

//call the function on click using '$(this)' as a parameter

$('div.destination a').click(function(){
    travelToDestination($(this));
}
```

Like I said, the code works fine as it is. I just want to know what I am doing wrong when I try and make it a function. It may be that 'this' does not equal '$(this)'. Thanks!

Comment: Does it throw an error?

Comment: Seems like the first thing I would suggest just for a clarity standpoint is this: `$('div.destination a').click(travelToDestination)` ...

Comment: You're right, `this` does not equal `$(this)`. You should just pass `this` to the function.

Comment: Waleed Khan: the error I get is this: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$( $.attr(x, 'href') ).offset().left')

Comment: How do you plan to reuse the code?

Comment: @jcolebrand by clicking a link the window will scroll to an href. but I also have links that determine the speed at which it scrolls and I want to reuse the function when a user changes the speed

Comment: So you will also want to pass in the speed as well?

Comment: yeah. Speed is saved as the variable TraveRate as seen above

Comment: So passing in speed means my answer won't work, which is something for you to learn in the future "full spec before work" ;-) rewrites are a pain in the bum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to:

```
$('div.destination a').click(function(){
    travelToDestination(this);
}
```

Since you replaced `this` with `x`, it expects the argument to be the DOM element, not wrapped in a jQuery object.

Comment: Better to just remove the anonymous function altogether, don't you think, since it just clutters the callstack?

Comment: @jcolebrand I saw your answer, I'm showing an alternative solution. Your answer requires him to recode the `travelToDestinaton` function, to go back to using `this` instead of `x`, because the argument passed to an event handler is the event, not the element.

Comment: Right, but I'm all for cleaner code in the first place. Let's teach new developers _how_ and _why_ to code a certain way, rather than letting them guess.

Comment: Your solution also makes it harder to use `travelToDestination` outside an event handler, since it will need to bind `this` explicitly. I don't know if that's what he meant by "use it here and there".

Comment: Now that, however, is something I did not consider. I assumed it would always be the invocation of an event handler. Good point.

Comment: should I be replacing all instances of `$( $.attr(this, 'href') )` with `x` instead?

Comment: No. You just replace `this` with `x`, as you did.

Comment: Although you can replace `$.attr(this, 'href')` with just `this.href`.

Comment: I can't even find documentation for `$.attr()`.

Comment: @Barmar You know what. I accepted jcolebrand's answer as the correct one and indeed it does work. But I think I have already run into the problem you suggested I might have in the future using his method. I want to pass in a variable that holds the "last destination clicked" so users can change speed on the fly. I can't pass anything into the function he suggested. But when I do as you suggest I get the error: TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$(this.href).offset().left')

Comment: @Barmar and you know what? I have no idea what $.attr(this, 'href') means either, I got it from some other stackoverflow post, but it works. I would like to get rid of it and use your suggestion `this.href` but again, I'm getting the above error.

Comment: Does the element you passed in have an `href`? Your function expects `x` to be an `<a>` element.

Comment: More specifically, it expects it to be something like `<a href="#id">`, so that it can scroll the corresponding element into place. If you call it on something without an `href`, you'll get that error. I don't think it matters which way you get the `href` attribute, the problem is that you're calling the function on something without that attribute.

Comment: yes, I just double checked. I call it (for now using his method) like this $('div.destination a').click.......and those anchors have hrefs like this `href="#sun"`

Comment: Wait a second. If you modified the function to be like I suggested, why do you still have `this.href`? It should be `x.href`.

Comment: no no no no I changed it back cause yours wasn't working. sorry.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39464/discussion-between-wetjosh-and-barmar)

Comment: I'm confused. Above you write _when I do as you suggest I get the error ... evaluating '$(this.href).offset().left'_. If you were doing as I suggest, you shouldn't be evaluating this.href.

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
$('div.destination a').click(travelToDestination);
```

and change all references to x back to `this`.  This way the `this` in your function is the button you clicked. At that point, what you have defined as x is the event of the click function, not the `this` element you had previously.

What you're doing when you do this is passing a function reference to the click handler, which is the same as passing the function itself. So instead of

```
$(selector).click(function _travelToDestination_inlineFunction(){ /* stuff */ })
```

you're just telling it to go find the function and use that. Also note the use of the named function in my "anonymous function" above. That always helps me with stack debugging later "where did I call that from again ..".

Second thing you did wrong: In the first one you're passing a `this` and in the second one you're passing a `$(this)` which you could bypass in the latter function (and leaving everything else alone) by adding this line:

```
function travelToDestination (me) {
    x = me[0]; //I added this line
    $('html, body').stop(true,false).animate({
```

but I wouldn't do that. I would just alter the first one.

Comment: hey I think that did it with one exception. You said change ALL references of `x` back to `this`. It threw an error when I did that. Then I deleted `this` from the parentheses after `function travelToDestination()` and it worked. Is that what you meant?

Comment: In the end, and after a long chat with Barmar, I went with Barmar's solution. I liked the simplicity of yours but like you both agreed upon, I would run into problems passing in the speed variable in later reuse. Everything is working beautifully now, and I thank you both very much for your help!

Comment: No worries at all, so long as you understand what we're both proposing, you come out ahead at the end of the day :D I try and take answers like this for a learning exercise more than "gotta boost the reps bro" ;-)